# React parent component props can't access using forwardRef props in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have Child Component Like this.

Parent => Child

When I send props to my child component from the parent component. The prop can't access child components.

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [renderCount, setRenderCount] = useState(4);

    const renderCountHandler = () => {
        setRenderCount(renderCount + 1);
    };

    return (
        <div>
           <Child renderCountHandler={renderCountHandler}/>
        </div>
    );
};


const Child = forwardRef((props, ref) => {

    //Can't access props.renderCountHandler Only props.children
    <div>{props.}</div>
});
```

I am a new student for reactjs. So I don't know much about it. If anyone can help me with this. It's a realy help for me to my studies.❤️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is ok in your code. I get the "renderCountHandler" props. See the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-leavitt-rhxh9?file=/src/test.js)

Comment: Thank you very much, sir..I forgot to consol log this.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `state` or `method` as `props` parent to child component.

Read more here [components-and-props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

**Example:**

```js
const { forwardRef, useState } = React;

const Parent = () => {
  const [renderCount, setRenderCount] = useState(4);

  const renderCountHandler = () => {
    setRenderCount(renderCount + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{renderCount}</p>
      <br />
      <Child renderCountHandler={renderCountHandler} />
    </div>
  );
};

const Child = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  //Can't access props.renderCountHandler Only props.children
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <button onClick={props.renderCountHandler}>Click Me</button>
    </div>
  );
});

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```